# library to use visual attributes of faces in an image for face recognition

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I am working on a project that uses visual attributes like gender, age, jaw shape, nose etc... for face recognition.But is there any library available that can do this operation?

Comment: [list-of-50-face-detection-recognition-apis](http://blog.mashape.com/post/53379410412/list-of-50-face-detection-recognition-apis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract faces from images, [`OpenCV`](http://opencv.org/) provides a [`Face Recognition`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/) API which you can use to detect faces in images. [`JavaCV`](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) is a Java Wrapper which should allow you to interact with it.

If on the other hand, you want to match those faces to actual people then you might want to use an [Artificial Neural Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network). You can take a look [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/faces.html) to get started. Alternatively, you can take a look at [Neuroph's face recognition](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/tutorials/FaceRecognition/FaceRecognitionUsingNeuralNetwork.html).

The good thing about neural networks is that they can be trained so that they are resilient to certain changes. Obviously pre-processing of the image will help in increasing the success rate of the face recognition.